# How to use correctly TextToSequences in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp

Here is a python script :

```
from zeugma import TextsToSequences

test = ['I am here to stay', 'Who are you', 'Hello World']

sequencer = TextsToSequences()
embedded_sequ = sequencer.fit_transform(test)
```

It return this error :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

How to solve this issue?

I try to give the same length to each element of test.

I expected to have a list of number for the return

Comment: More detail, I used this library : from zeugma import TextsToSequences

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into list of words:

```
test = [['I', 'am', 'here', 'to', 'stay'], ['Who', 'are', 'you'], ['Hello', 'World']]

sequencer = TextsToSequences()
embedded_sequ = sequencer.fit_transform(test)
```

Comment: I tried it. I have this output error : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.